# Find all $x,y$ that satisfy the inequality $x\leq 2(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: inequality

How to find all $x,y$ that satisfy the inequality $x\leq 2(x^2+y^2)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A general technique to solve such inequalities is to try to interpret the equation in a geometric way. Notice that the inequality can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 &\geq x/2 \\
x^2 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{16} + y^2 &\geq \frac{1}{16} \\
\left( x - \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + y^2 &\geq \frac{1}{16} \\
\end{align*}

Thus, the required set of solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are the points that lie outside the circle of radius $1/4$ centered at $(1/4, 0)$.